# Loss of precision in decimal display of double

Tags: java, double, precision

Why is there a discrepancy in the display of the following value?

```
double x = (double)988530483551494912L;
System.out.printf("%f%n", x);           -> 988530483551494910.000000
System.out.println(Double.toString(x)); -> 9.8853048355149491E17
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(x));  -> 988530483551494912
```

As you can see, both `toString()` and the `%f` conversion lose the precision of the last digit. However, we can see that the last digit is actually precise, because the `BigDecimal` conversion preserves it.

Comment: Documentation - `Double.toString`: "There must be at least one digit to represent the fractional part, and beyond that as many, but only as many, more digits as are needed to uniquely distinguish the argument value from adjacent values of type double."  ||  `%f`: " If the precision is less than the number of digits which would appear after the decimal point in the string returned by Float.toString(float) or Double.toString(double) respectively, then ... . Otherwise, zeros may be appended to reach the precision."

Comment: @user16320675 thanks, that explains it! Also, it can be demonstrated using `Math.nextAfter`.

Comment: Please write, post, and accept an Answer to your own Question, for posterity.

Comment: @BasilBourque as per your suggestion, I've answered my question, but on reflection I think my answer doesn't make sense. Why does it return `"9.8853048355149491E17"` when it could return one less digit, i.e. `"9.885304835514949E17"`, and still be distinguishable from adjacent values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @user16320675's comment, I'm answering my own question. The reason is that the number `988530483551494912L` has precision beyond the limit of the `double` type's precision, and `Double.toString()` (and similarly `%f`) will, as per documentation, only use the minimum number of significant digits required to distinguish a `double` number from adjacent numbers. Adjacent numbers are those that have the smallest representable difference from the original, on either side of it.

This can be demonstrated using `Math.nextAfter` to show the adjacent numbers:

```
import static java.lang.Math.nextAfter;
double x = (double)988530483551494912;
System.out.println(nextAfter(x, Double.MIN_VALUE));  ==> 9.8853048355149478E17
System.out.println(x);                               ==> 9.8853048355149491E17
System.out.println(nextAfter(x, Double.MAX_VALUE));  ==> 9.8853048355149504E17
```

So, as we can see, there is no point in adding any more significant figures because this string representation already has enough digits to distinguish the number from adjacent values.

However, a question still remains: it shows 17 significant figures, but 16 would be sufficient. I'm not sure why it issues an extra final digit.

Comment: It isn't 'at the limit' It is two decimal digits beyond the limit, which is 15.9 digits (i.e. only some larger integers can be represented accurately).